# always getting fix prediction for different records using decision tree algorithm

Tags: r, decision-tree

when using the decision tree to predict numeric values, I always get exactly the same predictions for different records, even when the independent variables in test data among records are different. What could be the reason?

Some lines of training data are below.

```
cur          val     lat    lon     ass     sf      nb  yr_bt   sasdate
562333.10    134000 33.7651 -84.266 178280  2214    4   1954    12158
201965.01    55900  33.7631 -84.270 22360   1352    2   1988    12240
322198.64    190000 33.7607 -84.264 75976   2258    2   1965    13322
355587.37    191500 33.7594 -84.2637 72520  2377    3   1961    12220
```

The code is below.

```
library(rpart)
x_train=subset(train,select=-c(origval))
y_train=train$val
x <- cbind(x_train,y_train)
x$yr_built<-as.numeric(x$yr)

#grow tree 
fit <- rpart(y_train ~ ., data = x,method="anova")

#Predict Output 
test$cur<-as.numeric(test$cur)
predicted= predict(fit,test)
```

Thank you.

Elyse